# Migrate Large Table from one Azure SQL Server to Another without GenerateScripts

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

At my organization, we have a table on one Azure SQL Server in which one of the columns contains a large JSON document.  This table also has over a thousand entries.  We need to migrate this table from one Azure SQL Server to another, but are running into issues with doing that.  We have generated scripts before to do similar processes however, the script generated for this migration is extremely large (due to the JSON document) and is unable to run properly.  Is there another tool/method for copying a large amount of data in a table between two Azure SQL Databases?  Thank you.

Comment: Is this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?tabs=azure-powershell) helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks for the help, my supervisor figured it out, and I am not completely sure, but I think he used a method similar to this.

Comment: Hi @AppSupportGuru1995. Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I don't see your answer below, otherwise I can mark it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways we can choose to copy to a new Azure SQL Server:

1. Copy using the Azure portal:
   [image]
2. Use PowerShell to copy a database to a new server according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/copy-database-to-new-server-powershell).
3. Copy using Transact-SQL according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool#copy-a-database).
   Copy to a different server:

```sql
-- Execute on the master database of the target server (server2) to start copying from Server1 to Server2
CREATE DATABASE Database2 AS COPY OF server1.Database1;
```